# Controlling Position of Boxes in DiagrammeR

Tags: r, visualization, diagrammer

I wondered if anyone could help with positioning of boxes in a Diagrammer flowchart, please?

In particular, on the third layer of the flowchart, I would like horizontal splits from 4-5, and 4-6. And also horizontal splits between 7-8, and 7-9.

Therefore, the growth out of nodes 2 and 3 is a two t-shapes. Would appreciate if anyone could help with this.

Thanks

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("digraph flowchart {
      node [fontname = Arial, shape = circular, fontsize=11]       
      tab1 [label = '@@1']
      tab2 [label = '@@2']
      tab3 [label = '@@3']
      tab4 [label = '@@4']
      tab5 [label = '@@5']
      tab6 [label = '@@6']
      tab7 [label = '@@7']
      tab8 [label = '@@8']
      tab9 [label = '@@9']

      # edge definitions with the node IDs
      tab1 -> tab2 
      tab1 -> tab3 
      tab2 -> tab4
      tab4 -> tab5
      tab4 -> tab6
      tab3 -> tab7
      tab7 -> tab8
      tab7 -> tab9
      
      ;
      }

      [1]: '1'
      [2]: '2'
      [3]: '3'
      [4]: '4'
      [5]: '5'
      [6]: '6'
      [7]: '7'
      [8]: '8'
      [9]: '9'
      ")
```

[image]

Edit for @benson23

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rank = same` to set nodes to same level. `dir = back` to reverse arrow direction and `group = left` to align nodes vertically.

I've cleaned up your code a bit.

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("digraph flowchart {
      node [fontname = Arial, shape = circular, fontsize=11]       
      tab1 [label = '1']
      tab2 [label = '2'; group = left]
      tab3 [label = '3'; group = right]
      tab4 [label = '4'; group = left]
      tab7 [label = '7'; group = right]
      tab5 [label = '5']
      tab6 [label = '6']
      tab8 [label = '8']
      tab9 [label = '9']
      tab10 [label = '10']
      tab1 -> tab10
      tab2 -> tab4
      tab3 -> tab7
      subgraph {
        rank = same; tab2; tab3; tab10;
        tab2 -> tab10 [dir = back]
        tab10 -> tab3 
      }
      subgraph {
        rank = same; tab4; tab5; tab6; tab7; tab8; tab9;
        tab5 -> tab4 [dir = back]
        tab4 -> tab6
        tab6 -> tab8 [color = white; arrowsize = 0]
        tab8 -> tab7 [dir = back]
        tab7 -> tab9
  }
}")
```

[image: flowchart]

Comment: Hi @ Benson23. Really appreciate your help there. Massive help. Would it be possible for you to show me how to change the second layer of the tree please? For example, suppoose I wanted a node (node10) in the middle, connecting vertically to 1, and connecting bi-directionally horizontally to nodes 2-3. Would it be possible for you to show me how that's done, please?

Comment: @EB3112 Updated, see if that helps. Actually the basics are already listed in my answer, you can play around with it to learn more :)

Comment: Thank you @benson23. I've voted+1 your answer. You've been a massive help. However, in terms of the second layer. I wonder if it can be configurated following the uploaded screenshot? When I do it like this, it butchers the third layer, sadly.

Comment: @EB3112 We can add an edge between `tab6` and `tab8`, and set `color = white` and `arrowsize = 0`. See code update :)

Comment: Thank you @benson23. Appreciate your patience